# How to compute final classification accuracy, precision, recall, f1-score, confusion matrix for a 1 vs 1 ensemble?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, svm, confusion-matrix

Consider a `3` class data, say, *Iris data*.

Suppose we want do binary *SVM* classification for this multiclass data using *Python's sklearn*. So we have the following three binary classification problems: `{class1, class2}, {class1, class3}, {class2, class3}`.

For each of the above problem, we can get *classification accuracy, precision, recall, f1-score and 2x2 confusion matrix*.

I have the following questions:

1. How to combine the results of these `3` binary classifiers and get a result equivalent to a multiclass classifier, i.e., how to get the final *classification accuracy, precision, recall, f1-score and a 3x3 confusion matrix* from above `3` accuracies, precisions, recalls, f1-scores and 2x2 confusion matrices?
2. Suppose we have `70%`, `80%` and `90%` accuracies for above `3` class combinations. Should I get the final accuracy as `accuracy.mean() +/- accuracy.std(),` and the same for other metrics?
3. Or, should I first get the final 3x3 confusion matrix, and from this matrix, I should compute accuracy, precision, recall, f1-score?
4. How does a multiclass classification do it internally? Does it use the strategy in **step-3**? I am not interested in directly applying multiclass classification, but only binary classification and get the result equivalent to multiclass classification.

Now, suppose we also want to perform `kFold` cross-validation with the above `3` binary classifiers. So for each fold we will have accuracies, precisions, recalls, f1-scores, and 2x2 confusion matrices. In this case, I can get the average accuracy as `accuracy.mean() +/- accuracy.std().`

Also, in case of `kFold` cross-validation, for each binary classification problem, I can get an aggregated confusion matrix by adding 2x2 confusion matrices for each fold. I can also compute average accuracy, precision, etc. across `kFolds` from this aggregated confusion matrix for each binary classifier. However, the results are slightly different than using `accuracy.mean() +/- accuracy.std()` across `kFolds`. I think latter is more reliable.

5. How to use `kFold` cross-validation for each binary classification problem, and get the final accuracy, precision, recall, f1-score and 3x3 confusion matrix?

I will appreciate if someone could answer above questions with implementation.

Below is minimum working example. Please note that a part of it is pseudo code for loading and splitting data in into `train` and `test` sets:

​

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score, precision_score, recall_score, classification_report, confusion_matrix
import time
import os

tic = time.clock()
# Import data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data                    
Y = iris.target

# Now, suppose we have three separate sets {data1, target1}, {data2, target2}, {data3, target3}
# for binaray classification.

#dataset = [{data1 + data2, target1 + target2}, {data1+ data3, target1 + target3}, {data2 + data3, target2 + target3}]

for d in dataset:

    #Import any pair, say, {data1 + data2, target1 + target2}. We will import 3 pairs one-by-one for 3 different binary classification problems.

    #data = data1 + data2
    #label = target1 + target2

    K = 10    #Number of folds
    for i in range(K):
        kf = KFold(n_splits=K, random_state=None, shuffle=False)

        cv = list(kf.split(data1))        
        trainIndex, testIndex = cv[i][0], cv[i][1]        
        trainData, testData = data.iloc[trainIndex], data.iloc[testIndex]
        trainData_label, testData_label = data_labe.iloc[trainIndex], data_labe.iloc[testIndex]

        # So now, we have Train, Test, Train_label, Test_label


        clf = []
        clf = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf')

        clf.fit(Train, Train_label)     

        predicted_label = clf.predict(Test)


        Accuracy_Score = accuracy_score(Test_label, predicted_label)
        Precision_Score = precision_score(Test_label, predicted_label,  average="macro")
        Recall_Score = recall_score(Test_label, predicted_label,  average="macro")
        F1_Score = f1_score(Test_label, predicted_label,  average="macro")

        print('Average Accuracy: %0.2f +/- (%0.1f) %%' % (Accuracy_Score.mean()*100, Accuracy_Score.std()*100))
        print('Average Precision: %0.2f +/- (%0.1f) %%' % (Precision_Score.mean()*100, Precision_Score.std()*100))
        print('Average Recall: %0.2f +/- (%0.1f) %%' % (Recall_Score.mean()*100, Recall_Score.std()*100))
        print('Average F1-Score: %0.2f +/- (%0.1f) %%' % (F1_Score.mean()*100, F1_Score.std()*100))

        CM = confusion_matrix(Test_label, predicted_label)

    print('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
toc = time.clock()
print("Total time to run the complete code = ", toc-tic)
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Yaroslav Surzhikov, my questions are not for finding a bug in some code, but to understand how theoretically something works. Additionally, I have requested an implementation. However, I can show existing Python code for SVM on Iris data.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service.

Comment: The main problem with your question is not that you're not showing your own code imho, the problem is that you're asking a few different questions all at once. You're basically asking for a complete pipeline for your classification problem. Try to solve each problem on your own and if you get stuck take that code, post it here and ask a specific question about that particular issue you're facing.

Comment: @Yaroslav Surzhikov, I already provided sample code. And so far I have not received any answer to my 5 questions above.

Comment: @ displayname, ok, so can you please answer the first 3 questions because in fact that is one question divided in 3 parts. If you read the 4th question that has nothing to do with my own working pipeline but to understand how multiclass classification does it internally. You can ignore 5th question for now if you think I am asking too many questions at once.